# How to get the average value from the firebase realtime database

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My question is about getting the Avg rating from the database, and then updating the average rating every time a row is added.
This is the structure of my database in firebase. 
[image: Firebase Real-time Database structure]

I am trying to retrieve the Average rating of each ID (number like 299536), and update it every time new data/row is added for the same id. 
I am using Firebase Realtime Database. 
Any help is appreciated. I am using react.js. Should I create an action for this?

Comment: How are you calculating the avg rating now?

Comment: I was thinking of trying this way, 
const oldAvgRating = firebase.database().ref(`movieinfo/${movieId}/avgRating`);
Then get the count of the rows for ID then, Add the current rating to the oldAvg and then divide by the count of rows +1.

Comment: That would give you access to the avg rating - yes...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly - something like this:

```
database.ref(`movieinfo/${movieId}/avgRating`)
  .once('value')
  .then((snapshot) => {
    const val = snapshot.val();
    console.log(val);
  })
  .catch((e) => {
    console.log('Error fetching data', e);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend abstracting this logic from your client side as you could have other apps and leaving open the avgRating for anyone to update wouldn't make it trust worthy. You can use a Cloud Function trigger for every rating that is created and run your logic there in a trusted environment and recalculate and update your avgRating [Heres a page from the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/extend-with-functions) that explains creating a function

```
exports.calculateAvgRating = functions.database.ref('/moveinfo/{moveId}/{rating}')
    .onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
        // LOGIC GOES HERE e.g.
        // Get a list of all your ratings
        // Get average rating
        // Update avgRating
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a cloud function to do this. Lets use a *onCreate* listener to average the total each time theres a write.

```
export const ratingAvg = functions.database
 .ref("ratings/{userId}/{recordId}")
 .onCreate(async (snapshot, context) => {
 const data = snapshot.val(); // rating obj (user, userPhoto, date, comment?, rating)
 const userId = context.params.userId; // this is your userId
 const transactionId = context.params.transactionId; // the uid of the record

 const profileAvg = await admin
  .database()
  .ref(`ratings/${userId}/`)
  .once("value");

  //' if avgRating exists average with new rating else use new rating.
  const newAvg = profileAvg.val().avgRating
  ? ((profileAvg.val().avgRating + data.rating) / 2).toFixed(2)
  : data.rating; 

  // write new average
  return admin
   .database()
   .ref(`ratings/${userId}/`)
   .update({
     avgRating: newAvg
   })
   .then(res => {
     console.log(res);
   })
   .catch(err => {
     console.log(err);
   });
 });
```